# Windows Failover Cluster Generic Script Resource: How to get IP-Address?

Tags: windows, cluster-computing, failover, failovercluster

I have a generic script resource (vbs). This script needs the cluster application ip address.

ATM the IP is configured in the script. But I would like to get it from the cluster (maybe from the resource object?).

I know I can configure a private property but the script is to be installed on several clusters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know the name of the cluster application. So, calling a *.ps1 from the *.vbs, I solved it like this:

```
$IPAddress = (Get-ClusterGroup -Name "MyClusterApplication" | Get-ClusterResource -name "IP Address *" | Get-ClusterParameter Address).Value
```